# Get the right exchange rate from the internet

Tags: excel, vba

For my Excel calculation table I need the actual exchange rate. Find and copy the exchange rate from the internet is no problem. My problem is, that the value which I copy from the internet explorer will not shown as the right number format.

For example, I want the exchange rate for the Argentinian Peso (€1 = ARS 49,9341). I copy the value from the internet explorer and want to past it into my sheet, unfortunately the number format of the value will be shown as €1 = ARS 499.341

Here is my code:

```
'Create Internet Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.finanzen.net/waehrungsrechner/euro_" & currency_value

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

value_to_copy = IE.Document.GetElementByID("currency-second-input").Value
currency_value = Split(value_to_copy, " ")
    
Range("L12").Value = "Price in " & currency_value(0)
Range("K8").Value = currency_value(1)  'This value will shown as 499.341
```

Here the HTML-part where I copy the exchange rate of the website:

```
<input value="USD 1,1189" id="currency-second-input" onclick="this.select();" onkeyup="calculateCalculator(true, 'currency-second-input', false)" style="width: 50%; float: left; height: 51px; padding: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #0066cc; font-weight: bold;" type="text">
```

In my test runs this problem doesn't always occur. If I need the exchange rate for the Colombian peso (€1 = COP 3.623,5878), it will past the right value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind it being a string you could paste with "'" in front. You can use faster xhr rather than opening a browser.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft HTML Object Library
Public Sub ExchangeRate()
    Dim html As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.finanzen.net/waehrungsrechner/euro_argentinischer-peso", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "'" & html.getElementById("currencyExchangeRate").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: this is brilliant. thank you very much. it works totally fine :)